# Target pages using Woo Commerce single product page template

Tags: page-template, woocommerce-offtopic, single

How do I target on woo-commerce single product page when adding a script I've created only for that particular page?

Comment: `is_singlular('product')` would do that or use particular page id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_product()` WooCommerce conditional tag to identify if its single product page. Below is example code which enqueues **test.js** if its a single product page. You may use and tweak this code snippet further.

```
function mytheme_scripts() {

    if ( is_product() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'test-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array() );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );
```